# how to customize Material ui table cell so text inside of it will take two lines instead of one line?

Tags: reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I'd like to customize native Material UI cell so it would show two lines of text in it with ellipsis instead of one. Adding divs inside the cell and adding style to it will not work because of how table is currently implemented.

this is how it currently looks like:
[image: this is how it currently looks like]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/2076

Comment: For some reasons this solution does not affect the styling at all

Comment: I don't think that it's even possible right now to do that

Answer (score -1):

Using wordWrap solve my problem
Use wordWrap like below:

```
 <TableCell
                    style={{
                      whiteSpace: "normal",
                      wordWrap: "break-word"
                    }}
                  >Some Long content ......... 
</TableCell>
```

Comment: I do not believe this answers the original poster's question. I think this allows wrapping, but does not provide an ellipsis after two lines. This looks like it will display any number of lines. Could you clarify as to how this works, and perhaps provide a screenshot of the output of your example code (with actual long text not containing ellipsis within the text itself)?